# How to prove that a series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given three series $A_n \leq B_n \leq C_n$, I should prove that $B_n$ is convergent if the series of the partial sums of $A_n$ and $C_n$ are convergent.

Comment: @Mohamad: You're mixing up [sequences and series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Series). Usually one is interested in the **sequence** of partial sums of a sequence, or the **series associated to** a sequence (the series whose terms are precisely that sequence); and $A_n$, $B_n$, and $C_n$ are themselves sequences, not series.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157853/proof-of-a-test-for-series/157862#157862)

Answer (score 2):

That need not to be true. Take an increasing sequence $A_n$ that converges to $-1$ and a decreasing sequence $C_n$ that converges to $1$. Then take $B_n = (-1)^n$. Clearly the relation you state holds, but $\lim B_n$ does not exist. What I think you're looking for is the so called squeeze theorem:

**THEOREM**

Let $a_n < b_n < c_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Then if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n=\mu \in \Bbb R$ we also have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \mu $.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich_theorem) here. It is quite useful in calculating limits of functions. See it might work for series as well because you are using the concept of convergence of the series of partial sum of $A_n$ and $C_n$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, the hypothesis must be strengthened very slightly.  We will assume not only that the partial sums are bounded, but also that the partial sums of $A_n$ and $C_n$ approach a limit, which we will denote $\sum A_n$ and $\sum C_n$, respectively.

By the first inequality, $C_n-A_n\ge B_n-A_n \ge 0$.

$\sum B_n-A_n$ is monotonic (since each successive term is positive) and is bounded above by $\sum C_n-A_n$.  A monotonic sequence bounded above converges to a limit$^1$.  Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n - A_n$ exists and $\sum B_n$ converges.

$^1$This sequence is monotonic increasing, so the limit of the sequence is the least upper bound of the sequence itself.

Comment: ???  A sequence can be bounded above and below and still not converge.  I suspect that Mohamad is leaving out some important details of the problem.

Comment: I need to edit it still...sorry.

Comment: How do you know that $\sum C_n-A_n$ converges?

Comment: Because $\sum C_n - A_n = \sum C_n - \sum A_n$, and $\sum C_n$ and $\sum A_n$ both converge.